# How do I check a New Zealand eVisa issued at the border to a UK visa waiver traveller?

Tags: visas, new-zealand

Recently I entered New Zealand as a British citizen, using the 6-month visa waiver approach where you are issued a visa at the border.

I entered via Auckland airport, where I was directed to use the "New Zealand, Australian and British passport" electronic gates.

The gate issued me a 6-month visitor visa, which I was expecting.  However, there is no physical evidence of this visa - the gate issued no print out, there was no human presence to issue a stamp etc etc.

**If I needed to verify dates for my visa, other than dates of travel (which can become confused if travelling a lot), how would I go about it?**

The online options seem to all be for other types of visa, for employers or other officials where a visa document (electronic via email or otherwise) was issued.

Comment: The question that arises here is, who do you need to verify dates with?

Comment: @GayotFow no one, its more of an academic question - other than the gates screen saying "you have been issued with a six month visitor visa", I have no evidence of that for myself or other people.  A call to immigration sorted it (visa now shows in their online checker) just via giving my passport number, but the online checker requires specific knowledge of the visa in order to query said visa, which a frequent traveller may not have.  For instance, my visa is shown as a single entry visa, and is ended when I hop to Aus, and I get a new visa when coming back...

Comment: ... but that new visa may be a six month one, it may be a four month one, it may be a three week one  and it may even be a multiple entry one - but it's a *new* visa with a new start date. With no physically issued (stamp, paper or email) visa with a visa number, it could easily become confusing about current visa details.  Hence my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New Zealand Immigration provides a [Check my visa conditions](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/already-have-a-visa/check-your-visas-conditions) online tool which you can use.

> You can check the visa conditions that you need to comply with during the duration of your visa online or inside your passport.

You say you have looked at "online options", but I don't see anywhere on the above page that says you can't use it to check for the conditions of an ordinary visitor visa.

One of the required details is visa start date. For an electronic visa, that would be the date you entered New Zealand. If you don't know what date *that* was, then call your airline.

Comment: As I said in my question, "other than dates of travel", so this option is out - there are numerous reasons I might not know which entry I gained this visa on, so it's not as simple as "call your airline". As an aside, that site also doesn't come up with anything for my passport number and the date of entry...

Comment: Then [call Immigration](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/contact) and talk to somebody. They're quite friendly.